# How to solve this pair of differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equations are

$$y' = y + 3z$$$$z' = -3y + z$$I vaguely remember I need to differentiate one to get the form of the other, but by differentiating the first and subbing in the second I get$$y'' = y' + 3z'=> y''- y' + 9y = 3z$$ I don't know what to do from here.

Edit:
From here I got to $y''-2y'+10y = 0$, so from $m^2-2m+10=0$ we get$$y=e^x(Acos(3x) + Bsin(3x))$$Where would I go from here?

Comment: $z = (y'-y)/3.$

Comment: Small correction above.  $y'' - y' + 9y = 3z$

Comment: @MathPhys Thee equations needed to solve three variables $(x,y,z)$

Comment: Hint: $(y\pm zi)' = (1\mp 3i)(y\pm zi)$

Answer (score 1):

From the first equation, $z = \frac{1}{3}(y'-y)$ and $y'' = y' + 3z'$. From the second eqution, $z' = -3y+z = -3y+\frac{1}{3}(y'-y)$. So, $$y'' = y'+ 3(-3y+\frac{1}{3}(y'-y)) \\ \Rightarrow y'' - 2y' + 10y = 0 \\ \Rightarrow y = (A\cos(3x)+B\sin(3x))\exp(x) $$

Recalling that $z = \frac{1}{3}(y'-y)$, we first calculate $$y' = y + (B\cos(3x)-A\sin(3x))\exp(x) $$

and so

$$ z = \left(\frac{B}{3}\cos(3x)-\frac{A}{3}\sin(3x)\right)\exp(x) $$

Answer (score -1):

Your equation is
$$x'(t)=Mx(t)$$
Where
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\-3&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$x(t)=\begin{bmatrix}y(t)\\z(t)\end{bmatrix}$$
Which has the solution
$$x(t)=e^{Mt}x(0)$$

Comment: What is the reason behind the downvote?

Comment: I think people don't really like matrix exponentiation around here. Just have a look at the similar fate of my answer

Comment: @Federico Yes, sadly. But it's more elegant :)

Comment: Honestly, it's also objectively useless for the OP, though

Answer (score -2):

$(y,z)'=A\cdot(y,z)$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\-3&1\end{pmatrix}$. Hence
$$
(y,z)(t) = \exp(tA)\cdot(y,z)(0)
$$

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct. Maybe go read about matrix exponentiation instead of downvoting

Comment: Maybe wonder whether your post can possibly be useful to the OP, from what one can guess of their background, rather than fulminating against voters. (BTW, I didn't vote but I am tempted to.)

Comment: @Did It might be useful, if for nothing else, at least as an invitation to learn about [matrix exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: @Did Also, I've never downvoted correct answers. At least leave them alone if you don't find them particularly useful. To me a downvote is to signal that something is wrong, misleading, very badly presented, etc...

Comment: You might want to try holding this rather fragile position -- but then please do not be surprised  when others do not follow you and act accordingly.

Comment: @Did Now I've learnt not to be surprised by that :-)

Comment: In any case, you might want to avoid giving orders to others, simply because they tried to inform you.

Comment: @Did Which orders did I give you?

Comment: Huh? A suggestion, and then I am out: perhaps reread your own comments?

Comment: @Did I don't understand. I just said that that is my personal policy and I find it reasonable. I didn't say that I truly expect anybody to abide by it.

Comment: @Did Oh I see, you refer to _"At least leave them alone if you don't find them particularly useful."_, right? That's probably my bad, as english is not my first language. It wasn't meant as an order. I don't know how to express that properly. I think it's called [generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you), but I might be wrong